# Which data type is better when insert a record to the database using id generator method?

Tags: java, postgresql, sqldatatypes

My table is called `tb_student` in Oracle. Its id is NUMBER(9). I  find that using the jdbctemple to search the id can be defined by string. The java code runs well. But now I want to migrate the database from Oracle to PostgreSQL.

After the migration, the java code was wrong. So I changed the id from `numeric` to `varchar`, and I do not need to change the table index. The code runs well. But my boss say that I should not change the table, and I should change the Java code to change the id type to Long.

Which way is better? Should I change the column's data type? Or should I change the java code? Which is best?

Comment: Sounds like your Java code is wrong (treating a number like a string). Your boss is right I think.

Comment: The column should have been migrated to an `integer` not a `numeric` type, but apart from that: your boss is right. It sounds as if you are using `LIKE` on a number column which might have worked in Oracle, but was a bad idea there as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your boss clearly is right, sorry.

The data type should match the actual data and not chosen based on an accident that happened in the code.

The number one reason is that you can only store integer values in a `numeric(9)` column, so there is no danger of letters creeping in. Also, think of leading zeroes or spaces that would cause values to be different, even if they are the same numerically. Finally, you are in trouble with query conditions using `<` or similar, because the semantics for strings are different.

Answer (score 2):

Your column called `ID` so from modeling perspective it should be number, beside it depends on many things, if this column/table is new you can change from database level, or then you have to make sure it doesn't have foreign key or procedures using this column `ID` as number or even in the java code is not using it as int. There is no best practice here but it seems is better to change from java code.